# Angular js tabs content HTML tags not rendering

Tags: html, angularjs, tabs

I have one angularjs application. In that application if we click button we are displaying some content which have tabs. By clicking each tab corresponding data will be fetch and need to display there. So data i am getting dynamically. But problem is in below example, i have HTMl tags in content(EX:- "address":"`<b>NewYork</b>`"). But when i click address tab, it is displaying like `<b>NewYork</b>`,instead i need **NewYork** Kindly suggest me

```
$scope.tabs = [
       { title:'id', content:data[0].id, active:true },
       { title:'name', content:data[0].name,active:false},
       { title:'address', content:$sce.trustAsHtml(data[0].address),active:false},
       { title:'pin', content:data[0].pin,active:false}
];



<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" >
            <a href="" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" ng-click="select(tab)" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" style="width:100%">
        {{tab.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using `to_trusted` filter

```
<a href="" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" ng-click="select(tab)" data-toggle="tab" ng-bind-html="tab.title | to_trusted"></a>
```

and add filter in your js side

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    //some code               
}).filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default angular sanitizes your values to display any HTML tags as text, for obvious security reasons. If you want to include HTML from your objects in your templates, you can use the ng-bind-html="yourvalue" directive on your HTML elements, ie:

```
<span ng-bind-html="yourvalue"></span>
```

Or specifically for your case:

```
<a href="" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" ng-click="select(tab)" data-toggle="tab" ng-bind-html="tab.title"></a>
```

Keep in mind though that this isn't really a best practice in angular (tempting though it is, I've used it too often myself already). It all depends on your particular situation of course, but in general you might want to include this kind of markup in your template and/or include some property in your model with some significance and adjust your display based on that. For example, if *city.isFavourite* is true, you could conditionally add a *favourite* CSS class to it in your template.

To wrap it up, this page goes into some safety considerations when using HTML verbatim in your template: [AngularJS API for $sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for reply.. But here i am getting content data by repeating tabs array.so i have data in tab.content. So how can i use ng-bind-html?If you dont mind can you provide me sample code which i have given.

Comment: I've added an example more specific to your code, I hope I got it right. Maybe it helps to note that ng-bind-html replaces {{ tab.title }}, which is kind of shorthand for ng-bind (when it's the only content in your tag that is).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys. It is working fine now. I kept like below.

```
<div ng-bind-html="tab.content"></div>
```